# Can't iterate filtered Dictionary in Swift

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I'm currently developing an app in SwiftUI for the first time and I've run into an issue I don't quite understand.
What I'm ultimately trying to achieve is to fetch data from a backend API I've already built and to display that in a sort of "calendar" view inside the app. I'm trying to list all the events of the day on the screen with a DatePicker at the very top to choose the the date. I've built this up with a dummy dictionary of data to first try to get the looks of it right.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct EventDot: View {
    let minute: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        let position = CGFloat(minute) / 60.0
        
        if position < 1 {
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .frame(width: 13, height: 13)
                .offset(x: position * UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("Tapped at minute \(minute)")
                }
        } else {
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
}

struct PlanView: View {
    let minutesArray: [Int: Int] = [0: 15, 15: 1, 12: 36, 7: 55]
    
    @State var selectedDate = Date.now
    
    @State var events: [Int: String] = [:]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(selectedDate, style: .date)
            DatePicker("Datum", selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: [.date]).bold()
            
            Divider()
            
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(0..<24, id: \.self) { hour in
                        Text("\(hour):00")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding(.leading, 10)
                            .padding(.top, 40)
                            .font(.headline)
                        
                        ForEach(events.filter { $0.key == hour }, id: \.self) { key, value in
                            
                        }
                        
                        if let minute = minutesArray[hour] {
                            EventDot(minute: minute)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 0)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        }

                        Divider()
                            .background(.black)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            events = minutesArray.reduce(into: [:]) { result, pair in
                let (hour, minute) = pair
                result[hour] = "Event at \(hour):\(minute)"
            }
            
            print(events)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    PlanView()
}
```

This code works fine, except that whenever I try to filter/iterate over the events of a specific hour, Xcode shows me this:

> Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs)

Either I've found a bug in Swift or I'm missing something that Xcode is only displaying in a cryptic message.

I've realised that filtering the dictionary is pointless and what I actually wanted to achieve was to get an Int array from the dictionary and iterate through that array. I've changed my code so the events state now is a [Int: [Int]] dictionary and it still won't let me iterate over that array.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct EventDot: View {
    let minute: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            let position = CGFloat(minute) / 60.0
            let dotSize: CGFloat = 16
            
            if position < 1 {
                let xPosition = (geometry.size.width * position + dotSize) / 2
                
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .frame(width: dotSize, height: dotSize)
                    .offset(x: xPosition, y: (geometry.size.height / 2) - 2.5)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("Tapped at minute \(minute)")
                    }
            } else {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PlanView: View {
    @State var selectedDate = Date.now
    
    @State var events: [Int: [Int]] = [0: [15], 15: [1], 12: [36], 7: [59, 44]]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(selectedDate, style: .date)
            DatePicker("Datum", selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: [.date]).bold()
            
            Divider()
            
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(events.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { hour in
                        Text("\(hour):00")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding(.leading, 20)
                            .padding(.top, 40)
                            .font(.headline)
                        
                        
                        ZStack {
                            if let event = events[hour] {
                                for array in event {
                                    
                                }
                            }
                            
                            /*ForEach(Array(minutesArray.filter { $0.key == hour }.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { key, element in
                                
                                EventDot(minute: element.value)
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            }*/
                        }

                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(.black)
                            .frame(height: 1)
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    PlanView()
}
```

Now it shows a different error which I still can't make any sense of: "Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'some View' conform to 'AccessibilityRotorContent'"

Comment: It is a typo, comment out sections until you find it

Comment: `filter`ing a dictionary is pointless. It's a requirement that dictionaries have unique keys, so you will get always a dictionary with a single key-value pair (or an empty dictionary). In practice this is the same as retrieving the value for the given key directly. The for loop is pointless too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because of your `ForEach(events.filter...`. No need to file a bug.

Try using something like this instead:

```
 ForEach(Array(events.filter { $0.key == hour }.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { key, element in
     HStack {
         Text("key: \(key) ")
         Text("value: \(element.value) ")
     }
 }
```

EDIT-1:

given the valid comments regarding pointless filtering on the `key`, you can certainly display the info for the given `hour`
without it. Just use:

```
 if let event = events[hour] {
     HStack {
         Text("hour: \(hour) ")
         Text("value: \(event) ")
     }
 }
```

If however you want the filter on the `value`, then the approach
using

```
  ForEach(Array(events.filter { $0.value == .....
```

is appropriate.

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain to me why you did what you did or what specifically was wrong with what I was doing? It would help me a lot in understanding what I did wrong for the future

Comment: Yes, you should file a bug. Apple needs to know that there is a bug in the Swift compiler.

Comment: `ForEach` is for providing views based on a `RandomAccessCollection` of some data type.
 A `Dictionary` is not such a collection. Hence the `Array(...)` wrapping.
 See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach
 There are other ways to loop over your dictionary keys, or values.

Comment: @F4LS3 see the comment by vadian above to understand what really is wrong, there is no point in filtering a dictionary by key since the keys are unique. You might as well use a subscript direct, event[hour], and without a loop since you will always get back 0 or 1 object. So one could argue that this answer is a bit misleading.

Comment: I agree that filtering the dictionary is redundant. I'll update my answer.